# jquery: how do I find index of child divs with the same class

Tags: jquery, class, indexing, parent-child

Here's the problem; I have a div which contains child divs within itself and I can't seem to access the child divs.  What I need is to find the index with .eq90 for each of the child divs.

Here's the code that generates the parent.

```
function makeSmallBlockdiv ()
{
var smallBlock = $('<div class="SmallBlock EditBlock"></div>').appendTo("#canvas");
smallBlock.draggable({containment: "#canvas", scroll: false, grid: [10, 10]}, {cursor: "move", cursorAt: {top: 125, left: 150}})
smallBlock.append('<div class="article_title EditBlock fontCenter fontBold font24">Article Title</div>')
smallBlock.append('<div class="article_Image"><img style="width: 250px;" src="<? echo $image1 ?>"></div>')
smallBlock.append('<div class=" article_text font14"><? echo substr($article_text, 0, 200) ?></div>')   
}
```

This function can be called as often as needed to create more parent divs.
What I have tried so far is the following:

```
$(".article_text").click(function() {
  alert("Index: " + $(this).index());
});
```

I have wrapped this in a function ready() with change.  This code comes from a fiddle I found here http://jsfiddle.net/fY6SU/48/

The fiddle code works perfectly, but mine does nothing. When I look at my html with firebug, I can see the divs are gettig created properly.  I am stumped and it doesn't help that I am just starting out with jquery.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Chris

Comment: post YOUR *non working* html and javascript and not an example that works

Comment: This is my code. I just used the fiddle code as my own and change the class names.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".article_text").click(function() {
  alert("Index: " + $(this).index());
});
```

The selector is only selecting the class 'article_text', and the html you generate only contains one div with the class 'article_text', so the solution is to add a class to the divs with the same name or use muliple selector, like this:

```
$(".article_text, .article_Image, .article_title, .SmallBlock").click(function() {
  alert("Index: " + $(this).index());
});
```

Comment: Just tried what you suggested and nothing happened. Here is some code that I use to test the article_text class.$("div").children(".article_text").css("color", "red");
var t = $("div").children(".article_text").html();
alert (t); 
var t = $("div").children(".article_text").text('Hi from inside jquery');
This works except that I don't have access to each copy of article_text.

Comment: works for me,  im guessing this is what you want? [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fY6SU/68/)

Comment: Just figured it out.  Here's my code, not eelegant but it works.

  $("div").children(".article_text").eq(3).css("color", "red");

I put the css in just as a visual aid

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your Solution Lies in your class names. $(".article_text") select only the last div and , Consider renaming as per classnames in the example fiddle

Comment: What does changing the names of my classes have to do with finding the index of a child?

Answer (score 0):

`What I need is to find the index with .eq90 for each of the child divs.`

Here:

```
var ninetyChildren = new Array(); //create an array to hold the children
$(".parent").each(function() { //loop through each parent
    var ninety = $(this).children().eq(89).text(); //get index of 90 - eq starts with 0
    ninetyChildren.push(ninety); //add 90th index to array
});

$.each(ninetyChildren, function(i, data){ //loop through 90th indexes
alert(i +" "+ data); //alert each 90th index
});
​
```

Hope this is what you wanted.  [Mock Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fY6SU/48/)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out how to get the index() for the siblings.

Here is the code that I used to find them.

```
$("div").children(".article_text").eq(3).css("color", "red");
```

The css selector is just there as a visual aid to confirm its working.

THanks to all who helped me.